# How can i merge two data frames in R by the same values in different columns using base or dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Let's say that I have two data frames In R :

The fIrst one:

```
cat = rep("xx",5);cat
fIrst = c("a","a","a","h","h")
second = c("b","c","d","b","c")
val1 = c(1,2,3,10,20)
A = tIbble(cat,fIrst,second,val1);A
```

that looks lIke thIs :

```
# A tIbble: 5 x 4
  cat   fIrst second  val1
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
1 xx    a     b          1
2 xx    a     c          2
3 xx    a     d          3
4 xx    h     b         10
5 xx    h     c         20
```

and a second one :

```
cat = rep("xx",5);cat
fIrst = c("a","a","a","b","c")
second = c("b","c","d","h","h")
val2 = c(100,200,300,400,500)
B = tIbble(cat,fIrst,second,val2);B
```

that Is :

```
# A tIbble: 5 x 4
  cat   fIrst second  val2
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
1 xx    a     b        100
2 xx    a     c        200
3 xx    a     d        300
4 xx    b     h        400
5 xx    c     h        500
```

I want to merge them but when I do It I get :

```
left_joIn(A,B,by=c("cat","fIrst","second"))
# A tIbble: 5 x 5
  cat   fIrst second  val1  val2
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 xx    a     b          1   100
2 xx    a     c          2   200
3 xx    a     d          3   300
4 xx    h     b         10    NA
5 xx    h     c         20    NA
```

because h Is In dIfferent column when I try to joIn them. Because the combInatIons are the same but In dIfferent order.

Ideally I want to look lIke  thIs :

| cat | fIrst | second | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xx | a | b | 1 | 100 |
| xx | a | c | 2 | 200 |
| xx | a | d | 3 | 300 |
| xx | h | b | 10 | 400 |
| xx | h | c | 20 | 500 |

how can I do that ? Any help?

**my attempt**

My attempt is the following :

```
Aa = left_join(A,B,by=c("cat","first","second"))
Aa
BD = B%>%rename(second=first,first=second);BD
full_join(Aa,BD,by=c("cat","first","second"))%>%
  dplyr::mutate(Val2 = coalesce(val2.x,val2.y))%>%
  dplyr::select(-c(val2.x,val2.y))%>%
  tidyr::drop_na()
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  cat   first second  val1  Val2
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 xx    a     b          1   100
2 xx    a     c          2   200
3 xx    a     d          3   300
4 xx    h     b         10   400
5 xx    h     c         20   500
```

but is there a more efficient way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this simply by binding the `val2` column to the first dataframe (tibble) using base R's `cbind` function.
`cbind(A, B$val2)` would do the job. You are having problems because `h, b & h, c` pairs are absent in the tibble `B` but you are expecting R to superimpose the values of `B$val2[c(4,5)]` in place where the `first` & `second` keys conflict in the tibbles A & B. You cannot expect R to magically bind data where there are conflicting keys. If you want to keep all keys you can use the `dplyr::full_join()` but it'll introduce `NA`s where there are conflicting keys. (By keys I mean the values you pass for the `by` argument!)

And it's a frowned upon practice to use equal sign `=` for assignments in R. Try using `->` instead.

Comment: thank for your answer but in my real world problem the B data frame has 500 rows with different combinations.So the `cbind(A, B$val2)` cannot hold.But any way I thought it would be a trick to "magically" bind them.Thank a lot for your effort.